# View Pager With large sized images scroll slowly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have implemented ViewPager to show images with TextViews, but the size of images(in drawable) is quite large and it scroll very slowly. When I have used small size images in ViewPager,it scroll smoothly. How can I make my ViewPager scroll smooth with large size images.
 My adapter code is:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new InfoFragone());
        fragments.add(new InfoFragtwo());
        fragments.add(new InfoFragthree());

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your adapter code here.

Comment: You should use Glide or Picasso to load your images, if not, you will continue to experience slow loading.

Answer (score 0):

Use the technique shown on this page :-

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html